# How to call up attributes in python 3.1 -- easy

Tags: python

Python 2.5 all you needed to do was type "dir(filename)" and that pulls up the attributes.

What is the command in 3.1?

Comment: unless I'm taking crazy pills this statement doesn't work.

Comment: You must be taking crazy pills. :P

Comment: In the REPL it'll work, in a script you'd obviously have to print(dir(theobject)) for it to display anything

Answer (score 3):

Just `dir(whateverobject)`.  Example:

```
Python 3.1rc1 (r31rc1:73141, Jun  2 2009, 12:50:02) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x=23
>>> dir(x)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
```

Please show us exactly what isn't working for you -- give us a chance to help!